# How can i remove display none from option tag inJquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I have tried to create a simple time picker for my project. There are two select options with 23 option values. When a user select one value from first select option, in that time value will be hidden on second select option with the help of display none css property by using Jquery. Next time user select next value from first select option i couldn't remove display none from old value from the second select option.

```
<body>
<div class="time-from"> 
<select id="TimeFromID" name="TimeFrom">
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="time-to"> 
<select id="TimeToID" name="TimeTo">
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
</select>
</div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$('#TimeFromID').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();    
    if(val)
    {
        $("#TimeToID option[value='" + val + "']").hide();  
    }
    else
    {
        $('#TimeToID option').css('display','block');
    }
 });

 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if statement just checked wether the selected value was truthy (and that applied to all options, so it didn't make any sense. You'll rather want to hide the option with the selected value and show all other options (= its siblings):

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$('#TimeFromID').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();    
    $("#TimeToID option[value='" + val + "']").hide().siblings().show();  
 });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time-from"> 
<select id="TimeFromID" name="TimeFrom">
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="time-to"> 
<select id="TimeToID" name="TimeTo">
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
</select>
</div>
```

I guess it might actually make sense in the context of a date range picker to not only show the selected value but also all lower values. So here's how to achieve that:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {

$('#TimeFromID').change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();    
    $("#TimeToID option[value='" + val + "']").siblings().show().end().prevAll().addBack().hide();
 });

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time-from"> 
<select id="TimeFromID" name="TimeFrom">
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="time-to"> 
<select id="TimeToID" name="TimeTo">
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Comment: The answer was very help full.

Answer (score 1):

On every change you should first show all the options, and only then hide the specific one that you just choose (on the first select).

Here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('#TimeFromID').change(function(){
    $("#TimeToID option").show();
    var val = $(this).val();    
    if(val) {
      $("#TimeToID option[value='" + val + "']").hide();  
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="time-from"> 
<select id="TimeFromID" name="TimeFrom">
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="time-to"> 
<select id="TimeToID" name="TimeTo">
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery you tried was not working on ELSE part. The better solution is to show all the option and then HIDE the option you don't wanted.

Below is the JQUERY you are looking for:

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(document).on('change', 'select#TimeFromID', function(event) {
        var val = $(this).val();    
        if(val)
        {
            $('#TimeToID option').show();
            $("#TimeToID option[value='" + val + "']").hide();  
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div class="time-from"> 
        <select id="TimeFromID" name="TimeFrom">
            <option value="01">01</option>
            <option value="02">02</option>
            <option value="03">03</option>
            <option value="04">04</option>
            <option value="05">05</option>
            <option value="06">06</option>
            <option value="07">07</option>
            <option value="08">08</option>
            <option value="09">09</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="time-to"> 
        <select id="TimeToID" name="TimeTo">
            <option value="01">01</option>
            <option value="02">02</option>
            <option value="03">03</option>
            <option value="04">04</option>
            <option value="05">05</option>
            <option value="06">06</option>
            <option value="07">07</option>
            <option value="08">08</option>
            <option value="09">09</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I think an answer is more helpful if you explain to the OP what your changed code does, instead of just saying "this will work".

Comment: Yes. Right. I will try to describe it.